# How to change EditText String format in runtime?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` to enter IBAN number. I want to format this

```
TR330006100519786457841326
```

while the user typing the input I want to for mat it like

```
TR33 0006 1005 1978 6457 8413 26
```

so basically I want to **add white space after each 4 digits**

I tried using `TextWatcher`, when `char sequence length` hits 4 I'm forcing a space but it doesn't work when user put "spaces"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base string way of doing this:

```
String input = "TR330006100519786457841326";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\w{4})", "$1 ");
System.out.println(input);

TR33 0006 1005 1978 6457 8413 26
```

Inside your text watcher, you can replace the string with the output generated by the above regex replacement.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String input = editText.getText().toString();
        input = input.replaceAll("(\\w{4})", "$1 ");
        editText.setText(input);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to give an example of what you might do.  Of course you may have to tweak what I wrote for your actual activity.

Answer (score 3):

Try using below regular expression:

```
input.replaceAll("....", "$0 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
    public static String insertSeperator(String text, String insert, int period) {// text= data, insert= <the data you want to be insert>, period= <Position>
text=text.replaceAll(" ","");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
            text.length() + insert.length() * (text.length() / period) + 1);

    int index = 0;
    String prefix = "";
    while (index < text.length()) {
        // Don't put the insert in the very first iteration.
        // This is easier than appending it *after* each substring
        builder.append(prefix);
        prefix = insert;
        builder.append(text.substring(index, Math.min(index + period, text.length())));
        index += period;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```